# Finding a parametric equation for an implicit cartesian curve

Tags: coordinate-systems, curves, parametric

The title really says it all: I want to know how to find a parametric equation for a curve defined by an implicit Cartesian equation.

I would imagine that this is impossible in general, but I'm curious about when it *is* possible.

I've search for a little while online, but the few resources I've turned up have been old and incomplete.  (See this reddit [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/c8afjh/how_to_convert_a_cartesian_equation_to_parametric/), for example.)

For context, I was trying to convert the equation $x^4+y^4=1$ into a parametric form.  (I am attempting to construct a library of "nice" convex parametric curves.)

Answer (score 1):

I've reread the reddit post I linked in my question a few times, and I've at least figured out how to construct a parametrization of $x^4+y^4=1$.
Recall the trigonometric identity $$\cos^2t=\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}.$$
We then set $x=\cos t$, so $x^2=\cos^2t$.  We know from the original Cartesian equation that $x^2=\sqrt{1-y^4}$, so then $$\sqrt{1-y^4}=\cos^2t=\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}.$$
Solving this for $y$ yields $$y=\pm\sqrt[4]{1-\left(\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}\right)^2},$$
so our desired parametrization is $$\left(\cos t,\pm\sqrt[4]{1-\left(\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}\right)^2}\right).$$
Using this approach, it can also be shown that a parametrization of $x^n+y^n=1$, where $n$ is even, is given by $$\left(\cos t,\pm\sqrt[n]{1-\left(\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\right).$$